# Search users that follows user

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to search users by ($_POST['search'] '"name" and "lastname"') that follows the

> "user id = 1"

I got the table users, in users I got

> "name" and "lastname"

And I got the table followers, in followers I got

> "follower_id" and "user_id"...

I know that to  do it I have to use models related, but I don't know how...

```
//$user_id = 1 (in followers.user_id)
//$_POST['search'] (in users.name and users.lastname)

public function u_followers_search($user_id) {

$followers = ...

return $followers;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Relationships' would be like this:

```
class User extends model 
{

   function followers()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'followers', 'user_id', 'follower_id');
   }

  function follows()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'followers', 'follower_id', 'user_id');
  }
}
```

And the query

```
User::whereHas(['follows'=>function($q) use($id){
  $->where('id',$id);
})->where('name',$request->name)->where('lastname',$request->lastname)->get();
```